# Owl Carousel Multiple images in one slide + randomize them

Tags: javascript, jquery, owl-carousel, owl-carousel-2

I am trying to make an Owl Carousel using (owl 2 plugin) with 3 slides where one of them has to have 2 or 3 items in it and display only one with a random order on load page.

Every time I refresh the page I want them displayed random.

I make a simple example here for better understanding:

```js
$('.owl-carousel').owlCarousel({
  loop: true,
  margin: 10,
  nav: true,
  responsive: {
    0: {
      items: 1
    },
    600: {
      items: 3
    },
    1000: {
      items: 5
    }
  }
})

var imageIndex = Math.floor((Math.random() * 2) + 1);
document.getElementById("randomSlide" + imageIndex).style.display = "block";
```

```css
.test {
  max-width: 400px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/OwlCarousel2/2.2.1/owl.carousel.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/OwlCarousel2/2.2.1/assets/owl.carousel.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/OwlCarousel2/2.2.1/assets/owl.theme.default.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

<!-- Set up your HTML -->
<div class="test">
  <div class="owl-carousel">
    <div>
      <img class="randomSlide1" style="display:none;" src="https://dummyimage.com/200x100/000/fff&text=test1">
      <img class="randomSlide2" style="display:none;"  src="https://dummyimage.com/200x100/000/fff&text=test2">
    </div>
    <div>
      <img src="https://dummyimage.com/200x100/000/fff&text=test3">
    </div>
    <div>
      <img src="https://dummyimage.com/200x100/000/fff&text=test4">
    </div>
    <div>
      <img src="https://dummyimage.com/200x100/000/fff&text=test5">
    </div>
    <div>
      <img src="https://dummyimage.com/200x100/000/fff&text=test6">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I've tried to use display: none for both images and to use this javascript method but doesn't work:

```
var imageIndex = Math.floor((Math.random() * 2) + 1);
document.getElementById("randomSlide" + imageIndex).style.display = "block";
```

Comment: This is unrelated to the Web Ontology Language, so I've removed the [tag:owl] tag.  Please be sure to read the tag descriptions when adding tags to questions.

Answer (score -1):

This is the solution thanks to [Bratu Sebastian](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9099676/bratu-sebastian)

```js
var owl = $('.owl-carousel').owlCarousel({
  loop: true,
  margin: 10,
  nav: true,
  responsive: {
    0: {
      items: 1
    },
    600: {
      items: 3
    },
    1000: {
      items: 5
    }
  }
});

function checkRandom() {
var slide = $('.owl-carousel .owl-item.active');
console.log( slide );
var imgs = slide.find('img');
var imageIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * imgs.length );
if( imgs.length > 1 ){
 imgs.css('display', 'none');
 imgs.eq(imageIndex).css('display', 'block');
}
}

owl.on('changed.owl.carousel', function(event) {
var slide = $(event.target).find('.owl-item').eq(event.item.index);
var imgs = slide.find('img');
var imageIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * imgs.length );
if( imgs.length > 1 ){
 imgs.css('display', 'none');
 imgs.eq(imageIndex).css('display', 'block');
}
});
setTimeout( checkRandom, 200 );
```

```css
.test {
  max-width: 400px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/OwlCarousel2/2.2.1/owl.carousel.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/OwlCarousel2/2.2.1/assets/owl.carousel.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/OwlCarousel2/2.2.1/assets/owl.theme.default.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

<!-- Set up your HTML -->
<div class="test">
  <div class="owl-carousel">
    <div>
      <img class="randomSlide1" style="display:none;" src="https://dummyimage.com/200x100/000/fff&text=test1">
      <img class="randomSlide2" style="display:none;"  src="https://dummyimage.com/200x100/000/fff&text=test2">
    </div>
    <div>
      <img src="https://dummyimage.com/200x100/000/fff&text=test3">
    </div>
    <div>
      <img src="https://dummyimage.com/200x100/000/fff&text=test4">
    </div>
    <div>
      <img src="https://dummyimage.com/200x100/000/fff&text=test5">
    </div>
    <div>
      <img src="https://dummyimage.com/200x100/000/fff&text=test6">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```